# How to redirect to non secure URL form Box API?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, box-api

How can I redirect to non secure URL from the successful authentication of Box API?

I'm trying to redirect to my application URL which is non secured, but it is showing the error `insecure_redirect_uri`.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Box OAuth 2.0 requires an SSL encrypted redirection unless you are redirecting to localhost.   We do this because credentials, and secret info like auth tokens shouldn't EVER be transmitted over the internet in the clear (i.e. must be encrypted).

We'll send it to you in the clear to localhost, because we're assuming that you're just doing some proof-of-concept hacking-an-example-together kind of work. We won't let you publish your application with that non SSL callback.

So you can just go into your app settings and set `http://localhost:4000` and you'll be fine for your quick [hello-world](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/wiki/HelloWorld) type program.